# Extjs GridPanel validation

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

how can i do a validation function that get me an error when IN1>OU1 or IN2>OU2 ??

this is my code (a grid panel with roweditor plugin)

```
{
 xtype: 'gridpanel',
 height: 250,
 width: 400,
 title: 'My Grid Panel',
 columns: [
           {
             xtype: 'datecolumn',
             text: 'IN1',
             dataindex 'F02ORAIN1',
             field: {
               xtype: 'timefield',
               id 'editF02ORAIN1'
             }
           },
           {
             xtype: 'datecolumn',
             dataindex 'F02ORAOU1',
             text: 'OU1',
             field: {
               xtype: 'timefield',
               id 'editF02ORAOU1'
             }
           },
           {
              xtype: 'datecolumn',
              text: 'IN2',
              dataindex 'F02ORAIN2',
              field: {
                xtype: 'timefield',
                id 'editF02ORAIN2'
              }
           },
           {
             xtype: 'datecolumn',
             text: 'OU2',
             dataindex 'F02ORAOU2',
             field: {
               xtype: 'timefield',
               id 'editF02ORAOU2'
            }
          }
 ],
 plugins: [
    Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.RowEditing', {
    })
 ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using getCmp (which you should never do unless debugging), get the data to compare to value from the Store.

Comment: could you post me an example please?

Comment: I think this should be a comment below the other answer. This way (out of context) it feels really strange. Maybe you don't have enough rep to post comments... here's some.

Answer (score 4):

I think the best way is to use field's [validator](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Time-cfg-validator) config:

```
// ...
{
    xtype: 'datecolumn',
    text: 'IN1',
    dataIndex: 'F02ORAIN1',
    field: {
        xtype: 'timefield',
        id: 'editF02ORAIN1',
        validator: function(value) {
            if (!Ext.getCmp('editF02ORAOU1').getValue()) return true;
            if (this.getValue() > Ext.getCmp('editF02ORAOU1').getValue())
              return 'IN1 should be less then OU1';
            return true;
        }
    }
}, {
    xtype: 'datecolumn',
    dataIndex: 'F02ORAOU1',
    text: 'OU1',
    field: {
        xtype: 'timefield',
        id: 'editF02ORAOU1'
    }
},
// ...
```

[Here is demo](http://jsfiddle.net/molecule/zzqtS/2/)

Comment: i've just try it but i receive this error:

Ext.getCmp("editF02ORAOU1").getValue() is null

but in my grid there are data in all columns of all rows!

how can i do?

Comment: @jack, I've updated my answer and added [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/molecule/zzqtS/2/)

Comment: thank you so much for your example!! i try it but i don't kno why i receive this error: values is undefined
[Interrompi per questo errore] return Function.prototype....ctor.apply(Function.prototype, args);

Comment: How about if you want to verify during form validation, whether the grid contains records (in which' case it is valid)?